# Language Cookies Issues

Tags: error, language, cookies

Scenario 1: A language other than English is selected.
New website.com visits will be in that language.
Even after switching back to English, websites will continue to load in the previous language.

Scenario 2: Website sticks to English on new visits regardless of which language is picked.

Scenario 3: A different language is selected. 
New website visits will remain on that language until another one is chosen.

Is there any way to disable saving of language cookies so as to always reproduce scenario 2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you save the cookie?

Comment: Not doing anything irregular. Just browsing the site, these 3 scenarios happened to 3 different people.

Comment: Well, you must be doing something. Craft doesn’t store any "language cookies" or randomly change the language for site requests to the same page. Can you update the question with some more info, how you can reproduce the problem and what URLs are used?

Comment: And maybe a list of saved cookies would be helpful, from your browser’s dev tools.